# Can I link auto-renewable subscription to app account?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

so I have implemented an authentication system on my app, and now I'm going to implement auto-renewable subscription.

I'd like to link a subscription to a user from my app, so if say:

1. User A creates an account on my app
2. User A buys a subscription
3. I record on my server that User A has a subscription
4. User A logs out from my app (but not from the device)
5. User A hands his phone to User B
6. User B logs into his account on my app
7. User B does not have access to the subscription bought by A, because even though it's the same Apple Id, on my server User A and B are different users.

Would this be allowed by Apple, or once a subscription is bought by an Apple Id, it has to be available regardless of in-app accounts?

Thanks.

Comment: User B uses the phone of User A without User A logout from apple-id?

Comment: Yes, it would be different accounts on my app, but with the same apple ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me summarize what's going on: If someone logs in to the app, your app must request the active subscriptions from the App Store.

If the iOS device is still logged in with user's A Apple ID, then your app will receive user A's subscriptions from the App Store. It makes indeed sense to expect that these subscriptions are then activated even though it's another user.

You could check with your server if the current subscriptions belongs to the user account and warn the user about any mismatch and ask to logout from the App Store.

But I'm actually not sure what Apple thinks about this scenario and it would be best to ask Apple.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i'm thinking also. Thanks

Comment: Hi Hilton, could you pls share Apple's response to this? Thanks.

Comment: @ram If you don't write @<user-name>, the user does not get a notification and will never know you've asked something.

Comment: @HiltonPintor, could you pls share Apple's response on this? I'm about to release an app with auto-renew subscription, and this would help me. Thanks meaning-matters (unable to @ you).

Comment: @ram I didn't end up contacting Apple. I decided to end up doing what was said on the answer, since I wanted to speed things along, and I didn't believe many users would do that, and even if they did, on my app it wouldn't be such a big problem. sorry.